# Which Calendar changed (Using EKEventStoreChangedNotification?)

Tags: swift, ekeventstore

I'd like to know more details about what has changed when the EKEventStoreChangedNotification gets fired. I have many calendars and don't want to reload all of them if in one of them a reminder/entry has changed. (Ideally I could reload just that calendar. Or even better, just re-add or delete that single reminder in my locally stored data structure.)

I saw the posting below but it wasn't answered and my question is more generic: Is there ANY mechanism (using EKEventStoreChangedNotification or something else) to get ANY more details on how the event store has changed?

[How to know which reminder is updated in EKEventStoreChangedNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821021/how-to-know-which-reminder-is-updated-in-ekeventstorechangednotification)

Thanks, Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the documentation is pretty blunt:

> Posted whenever changes are made to the Calendar database, including
>   adding, removing, and changing events or reminders. **Individual changes
>   are not described**.

It goes on to state that once that notification is posted, all of your Events are considered stale until you have re-fetched them.

So, unless you want to maintain a static database of events, and compare them all every time the notification posts, you are out of luck.